# How to show that Jacobi identity for $\{,\}$ is equivalent to $\omega$ being closed?

Tags: symplectic-geometry, quantum-groups, poisson-geometry

I am reading the book [a guide to quantum groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521558840). I have a question on page 18. How to show that Jacobi identity for $\{,\}$ is equivalent to $\omega$ being closed? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$, the Poisson bracket is given by $\{f,g\} = \omega(X_f,X_g)$, where $X_f$ is the Hamiltonian vector field. So the triple bracket expressions from the Jacobi identity of the form $\{f,\{g,h\}\}$ can be expressed as $\omega (X_f, [X_h,X_g])$, where we are using that $X_{\{g,h\}} = -[X_g,X_h]$. So now compare:

The Jacobi identity for the bracket says

$$ \begin {eqnarray}
0 &=& \{f,\{g,h\}\} + \{h,\{f,g\}\} + \{g,\{h,f\}\} \\
  &=& \omega(X_f, [X_h,X_g]) + \omega(X_h, [X_g,X_f]) + \omega(X_g, [X_f,X_h])
\end {eqnarray} $$

Now compare with the "coordinate-free" expression for the exterior derivative (see [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative), under the heading "in terms of invariant formula"):

$$ \begin{eqnarray}
d\omega(X_f,X_g,X_h) &=& X_f \omega(X_g,X_h) - X_g \omega(X_f,X_h) + X_h \omega(X_f,X_g) \\
&\phantom{=}& - \omega([X_f,X_g],X_h) + \omega([X_f,X_h],X_g) - \omega([X_g,X_h],X_f)
\end{eqnarray} $$

Using one more identity, that $X_f \omega(X_g,X_h) = \omega(X_f, [X_g,X_h])$, you can see that the top and bottom rows on the right hand side are the same, and so the right-hand side is twice the expression you get from the Jacobi identity. Since that is zero, so is $d \omega$.